# ImportError : No module named ryu.cmd.manager

Tags: python, import, controller, sdn, ryu

I wanted to try the command: pythonpath=. ./bin/ryu-manager ryu/app/simple_switch.py in ryu controller and this is the error message i got :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/ryu-manager", line 18, in <module>
    from ryu.cmd.manager import main
ImportError: No module named ryu.cmd.manager
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, python 2.7.17 and ryu 4.34

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, I am new to this too.
try running not using python, but run ryu-manager command directly.

Like:
May Be you are running like this

```
~/ryu/$ python ryu-manager ryu/app/simple_switch.py
```

**But try running ryu-manager directly like this:**

```
~/ryu/$ ryu-manager ryu/app/simple_switch.py
```